# Can iOS appllication be deployed on iPod touch device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipod-touch, iphone-5

I'm working on iOS application that is intended for iPhone 5. Since I don't have available iPhone 5, only iPod touch, I tried to debug it on iPod. But warning message "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS  simulator as the destination."
appears.

Anybody with same problem?

Comment: I bet your iPod touch is not iOS 6...but your deployment target is set to iOS 6.

Comment: No it was iOS 6, but had to add it to profile, and enable device for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK figured out my problem.

This device was not previously used for development.

1) First Had to go to my provisioning portal,

2) add the device's UDID,

3) add the device to development provisioning profile

4) download the profile, and double click on it to add it to Xcode's organizer

5) In Xcode's organizer select the device (iPod touch in this case), and press the button that enables the development on that specific device.

Now works with no problem.
Forgot to do this routine since I haven't been adding new devices for some time.

Hope this will help somebody.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added your iPod's UDID to your developer profile? Does your iPod have iOS 6 installed?

Thats' what the error message is telling you.

You need to have a provisioned device with the correct OS version installed to load an app onto it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to develop your application for the iOS Version of your iPod (e.g. your iPod is on iOS4, you need to develop for iOS4)